# Pairwise correlations over rolling periods ignoring double calculations

Tags: matrix, stata, correlation

I am trying to compute pairwise correlations over rolling windows for n= 40 variables where all rolled pairwise correlations for 2 given variables are saved in a new variable.

My dataset has the following structure:

```
Date        V1   V2   V3  . . .
01/01/2009  0.3  0.6  0.5
02/01/2009  0.1  0.5  0.2 
03/01/2009  0.7  0.1  0.1
.
.
.
```

The following code does the trick. **However, it fails to ignore the lower diagonal of the correlation matrix** (it estimates twice the correlation between vars + once the 1s on the diagonal):

```
ds (Date), not
gl vars `r(varlist)'

local i = 0
local j = 0

foreach current_variable1 in $vars {
local i = `i'+1 
 foreach current_variable2 in $vars {
local j = `j'+1 
    if (`j' > `i') {
     mvcorr `current_variable1' `current_variable2', ///
     generate(corr_`current_variable1'_`current_variable2') window(60) force

}
}
}
```

In particular the `if` condition on (`j > i`) intended to capture the doubled calculation of each pairwise correlation fails to do so. Including the `if` condition in the `mvcorr` yields only the error message `'no observations'`.

What could be the solution for this issue?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not resetting j to 0 each time you increment i, so (as it is now coded) j is always greater than i after the first time through the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@William Lisowski debugged your code in a comment, but you can simplify the whole procedure.

Create the tuples beforehand using the user-written command `tuples` (`ssc install tuples`).

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto
keep mpg weight price

gen time = _n
tsset time

*----- what you want -----

tuples price mpg weight, min(2) max(2)

forvalues i = 1/`ntuples' {

    local v1 : word 1 of `tuple`i''
    local v2 : word 2 of `tuple`i''

    mvcorr `tuple`i'', generate(`v1'_`v2') window(10) force
} 

describe
```

@William's advice leads to the same result:

```
local i = 0
local j = 0

foreach v1 of varlist `vars' {

    local i = `i' + 1 
    foreach v2 of varlist `vars' {

        local j = `j' + 1 
        if (`j' > `i') {
            mvcorr `v1' `v2', ///
            generate(`v1'_`v2') window(10) force

        }
    }

    local j = 0
} 

describe
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added tuples to my repertoire, but also, the original nested loops approach could be simplified along the lines of the following example.

```
local vars a b c
local n : word count `vars'
forvalues i=1/`n' {
    forvalues j=`i'/`n' {
    local v1 : word `i' of `vars'
        local v2 : word `j' of `vars'
        display "`i' `v1' `j' `v2'"
        }
    }
```